# How to find a worksheet newly created using xlcWorkbookInsert

Tags: excel-dna

With Excel-DNA, I can use

bool newSheet = (bool)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcWorkbookInsert, 1);

to create a new worksheet. This is given the name 'Sheetn' where n is one more than the number of sheets already in the Workbook.
Does anyone know how to use an ExcelReference to then pick up the new sheet?